# How to avoid code duplication here?

Tags: c#, oop, code-duplication, overloading, duplication

I have two flavours of a method in a class, one with an extra parameter

first one:

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv)
{
     initializations
     otherOperations

     for (int i=0; i < NUM; ++i)
     {
         SomeOtherOperations
         double v = GetV(a,b,c);
         SomeOtherOperationsUsing_v
     }

     restOfOperations
}
```

and second one:

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv, int index)
{
     initializations
     otherOperations

     for (int i=0; i < NUM; ++i)
     {
         SomeOtherOperations
         double v = GetV(a,b,c, index);
         SomeOtherOperationsUsing_v
     }

     restOfOperations
}
```

as you can see the only difference is that the first one calls GetV() with 3 parameters and the second one calls an overload of GetV() with 4 parameters.

How best I can avoid code duplication here?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely, there is a default index, that you could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .Net 4.0, you can make it an optional parameter:

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv, int index = -1)
{
    ....
    double v = index > -1 ? GetV(a,b,c, index) : GetV(a,b,c);

    ....
}
```

Comment: It's very close, but without more context, you can't be sure that GetV doesn't accept negative values for `index`.

Comment: Thank You Dave! obviously I need some coffee!

Comment: Can you ever have a negative index? I've never considered that philosophically :D ....

Comment: @DaveBish: The notion of a negative index is that you count backwards from the end. I.e. an index of -1 is the last element.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't know a reasonable default, a very simple way would be:

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv)
{
    CalcV(iv, null);
}

public override void CalcV(IV iv, int? index)
{
     ...
     double v = index.HasValue ? GetV(a,b,c,index.Value) : GetV(a,b,c);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Some of the other answers assume either 1) That GetV(a,b,c,0) == GetV(a,b,c) or/and 2) that `index` is strictly non-negative. This is not necessarily true now and in the future. My approach assumes neither.

Answer (score 1):

Having a guess at what GetV does (you'll need to change this to suit:

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv)
{
     CalcV(iv, 0);
}


public override void CalcV(IV iv, int index)
{
     initializations
     otherOperations

     for (int i=0; i < NUM; ++i)
     {
         SomeOtherOperations
         double v = GetV(a,b,c, index);
         SomeOtherOperationsUsing_v
     }

     restOfOperations
}
```

Comment: Yep, either that or default parameter - whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: Well... This will probably not do it since as you said you're guessing that `GetV` with three parameters does the same as `GetV` with four.

Comment: @Sani Huttunen - I agree - that's what the comment at the start of the answer is for - not enough detail in the original question, but gives the general gist of how to go about it...

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv, int? index = null)
{
     initializations
     otherOperations

     for (int i=0; i < NUM; ++i)
     {
         SomeOtherOperations
         double v = index != null ? GetV(a,b,c, index) : GetV(a,b,c);
         SomeOtherOperationsUsing_v
     }

     restOfOperations
}
```

Then you can remove the first override and this will deal with both scenarios.

Comment: This is really nice - the best answer since it's both short and correct without any assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was inspired by your use of null though!

Answer (score 0):

I assume `index` is 0-based and positive:

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv, int index)
{
  initializations
  otherOperations

  for (int i=0; i < NUM; ++i)
  {
    SomeOtherOperations
    double v = index == -1 ? GetV(a, b, c) : GetV(a,b,c, index);
    SomeOtherOperationsUsing_v
  }

  restOfOperations
}
```

Then you call the function with the index of -1 of you want to use `GetV` with three parameters or a "correct" index if you want to call `GetV` with four parameters.

```
public override void CalcV(IV iv)
{
  return CalcV(iv, -1);
}
```